# What is the proper word for 'newly formed flower'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am creating a wiki page and I am looking for an exact word for 'newly formed flower' with characteristics like fresh, young, charming, *etc.*

Comment: a charming flower?

Comment: I think we need to know more precisely the stage of the flower that you consider to be *newly formed*- A *bud* is the stage at which the flower is still tightly wrapped in the sepals. When the bud starts to open and the petals become exposed it is a *blossom*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't one word, but I think the best description would be a *budding flower*.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the flower buds finally blossom.

Comment: Well, blossom _is_ a word, and it can be used as a noun as well.

Answer (score 2):

*[Bloom](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloom)* may serve.  As a noun, its senses include

> — The opening of flowers in general; the state of blossoming or of having the flowers open.  (eg) *The cherry trees are in bloom.*
>
> — A state or time of beauty, freshness, and vigor/vigour; an opening to higher perfection, analogous to that of buds into blossoms. (eg) *the bloom of youth*
>
> — Anything giving an appearance of attractive freshness

Answer (score 2):

I know this is years late, but I thought I could contribute. The proper word for a flower opening would be 'Anthesis'. This is when in which a flower opens and becomes sexual active. Meaning it can accept sperm within its ovule and or deliver pollen.